# Declarar como atributo, un puntero a mi mismo tipo de variable en C++

Tags: c++, punteros, data-atributos

Mi problema es el siguiente: Tengo una clase `Nodo`, la cual tiene como atributo un arreglo de punteros `to` a su mismo tipo (como para hacer un árbol) y luego tengo una clase hija `NodoAvl` que debe heredar ese atributo pero los punteros deben apuntar a su mismo tipo, es decir, apuntar a `NodoAvl`. Quizás con mi código pueda explicarles mejor:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Nodo
{
    protected:

    T d;

    // Aquí necesito punteros a mi mismo tipo
    // así, Nodo tiene punteros a Nodo
    // y NodoAvl tiene punteros a NodoAvl

    "mi_mismo_tipo" *h[2] = {NULL};

    public:

    Nodo(T dato = T()) { d = dato; }
};

template <class T>
class NodoAvl : public Nodo<T>
{
    protected:
    int alt = 0;
    public:
    NodoAvl (T dato = T()): Nodo<T>(dato) {}
    int altu () {return alt;}
};
```

¿Existirá alguna forma de hacer esto? Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta de [Peregring-lk](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/32098/2742) es válida pero quisiera añadir algo a la misma.

Es común en casos como este declarar tipos anidados<sup>1</sup> en la clase para facilitar su uso:

```
template <class T>
struct Nodo
{
    // "Atajo" al tipo interno del nodo
    using value_type = T;
    // "Atajo" a la clase plantilla
    using my_class = Nodo<value_type>;

    Nodo(value_type dato = value_type()) { d = dato; }

protected:
    value_type d;
    my_class *h[2] = {nullptr};
};
```

Puede verse que `my_class` es un alias de `Nodo<value_type>` (siendo `value_type` un alias de `T`) que es precisamente lo que pides: *mi mismo **tipo de variable***.

Puedes extender esta práctica a la clase `NodoAvl`:

```
template <class T>
struct NodoAvl : public Nodo<T>
{
    using value_type = T;
    using my_node = Nodo<value_type>;
    using my_class = NodoAvl<value_type>;

    NodoAvl (value_type dato = value_type()): my_node(dato) {}
    int altu () {return alt;}
protected:
    int alt = 0;
};
```

Seguir este patrón facilita algunos usos y/o hace que el código sea ligeramente más legible, si tuvieras una función para obtener un nodo:

```
struct NodoAvl : public Nodo<T>
{
    using value_type = T;
    using my_node = Nodo<value_type>;
    using my_class = NodoAvl<value_type>;

    // Un poco mas claro que
    // const Nodo<T> &GetNode() const
    const my_node &GetNode() const;

    ...
 };
```

También te permite conocer el tipo `T`, del que no tenías conocimiento una vez instanciada la plantilla:

```
template <class T>
struct Nodo
{
    using value_type = T;
    using my_class = Nodo<value_type>;

    value_type GetDato() const;

    ...
};

using NI = Nodo<int>;
using NS = Nodo<std::string>;

NI ni; NS ns;

// Una vez hecho el alias o typedef, pierdes la "pista" del
// tipo subyacente del Nodo, a no ser que guardes el tipo
// en un tipo anidado.
NI::value_type i = ni.GetDato();
NS::value_type s = ns.GetDato();
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Puedes ver ejemplos en:
Contenedores stl como [`map`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map#member_types) o [`list`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list#member_types). Utilidades como [`initializer_list`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list#member_types) o [`pair`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair#member_types). También está presente este patrón en librerías como boost u otras librerías de código abierto.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <class T>
class Nodo
{
protected:
    T d;
    Nodo *h[2] = {NULL};

public: 
    Nodo(T dato = T()) { d = dato; }
};
```

Aunque la clase `Nodo` sea una clase incompleta en el punto de declaración de `h`, porque todavía se está procesando, siempre puedes declarar punteros, referencias y funciones que reciban o devuelvan objetos por valor de dicho tipo incompleto. Es decir, este código compila (aunque no lo he probado):

```
#include <iostream>

class A;

A* a = nullptr;
// A* a2 = new A; // [†]

struct B
{
   A& ra;  // [†2]
};

A f(A);
A& f(A&); // [†3]

// A& ra = *a; // [†4]

int main()
{}
```

**[†]:** Eso no compila porque, aunque sea válido declarar punteros a un tipo incompleto, no puedes crear ningún objeto de dicho tipo al no saber todavía de qué constructores dispones, y sobre todo, por no conoces todavía el tamaño de `A` (`sizeof(A)`).

**[†2]:** El caso `A&` lo he ejemplificado como atributo y no como variable local o global por no puedes declarar la referencia como variable (sea global o local), ya que las referencias deben estar obligatoriamente definidas en su declaración (por ejemplo, `ra = *a`), es decir, no puedes declarar una referencia, y asignarle un valor más tarde. Sin embargo, al ser `A` un tipo incompleto, no tienes forma de "conseguir" el objeto que quieres referenciar. Es decir, `*a` no compilaría por `A` es un tipo incompleto y no sabemos qué es un objeto de tipo `A`.

Sin embargo, sí que puedes declararlo como atributo, dado que ahí no estás obligado a inicializarlo. Eso ocurrirá obligatoriamente en el constructor, cosa que tampoco podrías implementar todavía hasta que `A` no esté definido.

**[†3]:** Los parámetros de las funciones son los únicos lugares en los que puedes declarar objetos de un tipo incompleto (y no solo referencias o punteros), dado que, en ese punto, no se necesita conocer ni su tamaño (`sizeof(A)`) ni su contenido. Eso sí, no podrías implementar la función hasta que `A` se defina más tarde en el código y ya haya disponible constructores de copia, etc.

**[†4]:** Nuevamente, no se puede aplicar `*a` si aún no conoces `A`. No conozco exáctamente los motivos, pero normalmente suele ser porque para realizar ese tipo de acciones el compilador necesita su `sizeof`.

Comment: El nombre del concepto que expones es [Forward declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) que yo traduzco como *pre-declaración*.

Answer (score 0):

El tipo no puede cambiar de forma mágica y milagrosa. Lo que puedes hacer es tirar de polimorfismo:

```
struct A
{
  virtual void func()
  { std::cout << "A\n"; }
};

struct B : A
{
  void func()
  { std::cout << "B\n"; }
};

A* a = new A;
A* b = new B;

a->func(); // Imprime A
b->func(); // Imprime B
```

Haciendo uso de esta característica lo único que tienes que garantizar es que la clase `NodoAv1` rellene el arreglo con elementos de tipo `NodoAv1`.

Vale, ahora ¿cómo puedes acceder a los elementos propios de `NodoAv1` si el puntero es de tipo `Nodo`?

```
struct A
{
  virtual void func()
  { std::cout << "A\n"; }
};

struct B : A
{
  void func()
  { std::cout << "B\n"; }

  void func2()
  { std::cout << "func2\n"; }
};

A* b = new B;
b->func(); // Imprime B
b->func2(); // ERROR!!!
```

La solución es utilizar alguno de los sistemas de conversión disponibles. En este caso, dado que sabes que en `NodoAv1` los punteros van a ser de tipo `NodoAv1`, puedes optar por usar `static_cast`:

```
A* b = new B;
b->func(); // Imprime B
static_cast<B*>(b)->func2(); // OK
```

Para ponerte un ejemplo más concreto haría falta que completases las clases de tu ejemplo para reflejar algún tipo de uso del arreglo.